# GRASS build polylines based on category/ID (v.net.distance)

Tags: grass-gis, distance, shortest-path, geodesic

I have calculated shortest routes between citywide origin-destination pairs with GRASS and v.net.distance. These routes are segmented, however, and I would like to turn them into polylines based on their cat (ID). Is there a way to do this, preferably in GRASS or QGIS?

| cat | distance | start_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 323 | 225 | 5 |
| 323 | 225 | 5 |
| 323 | 225 | 5 |
| 323 | 225 | 5 |

Alternatively, I could probably use v.net.path instead, but since the code is part of a long R script, I would rather avoid changes in the script.

Comment: Would the v.net.distance -l flag help? Another options is to look at v.build.polylines.

Answer (score 1):

Solution here is to use the v.net.distance `-l` flag:

> Write each output path as one line, not as original input segments.